# How to using regex match all content before these specific symbol in cpp?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to find a front(first) part before some symbols in a string. For example, `"ABC, ZXC"`, `"AB.QWE,CV"`, I want to get the result, `"ABC"` and `"AB"`. By the way, if there is some chinese character in this sentence, like "1月1日，天气晴" how to get the front part(1月1日)?

It is easier to reach in Python by

```
import re
front_part = re.findall(r'(.*?)[.,]', content)[0] if re.findall(r'[.,]',sentence) else content #if it didn't find symbols, then return the whole content.
```

However, I tried to use following codes in Cpp but it still returns the whole content:

```
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
std::string content = "AB.AC";
std::string front_part;
std::smatch frt_pt_sm;
std::regex frt_pt_patt(".*[.,]");
if (std::regex_match(content, frt_pt_sm, frt_pt_patt))
{
for(unsigned i = 0;i < frt_pt_sm.size(); ++i)
{
std::cout<< frt_pt_sm[i] << std::endl;
} 
front_part = frt_pt_sm[0];
}
return 0;
}
```

I am a novice in cpp so any suggesion is helpful for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ regexes don't have an equivalent to the `(.*?)` that you're using in Python.

In C++ you'll want to use something like: `[^.,]` to match the part up to (but not including) the first `.` or `,`.

On the other hand, given how simple of a pattern you're looking for, you could easily forego using regexes altogether:

```cpp
std::string input = "AB.QWE,CV";
auto pos = input.find_first_of(".,");
auto front = input.substr(0, pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first element of std::smatch is whole string. If you just want to find the first part of string before `.` or `,`, you can use this.

```
    std::vector<std::string> contents {"AB.AC", "AB.QWE,CV", "ABC, ZXC"};
    std::string front_part;
    std::smatch frt_pt_sm;
    std::regex frt_pt_patt(R"((\w+)(.|,)+(\s*\w+))");
    for(auto content: contents) {
        std::cout << "content: " << content << std::endl;

    if (std::regex_match(content, frt_pt_sm, frt_pt_patt))
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0;i < frt_pt_sm.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout<< frt_pt_sm[i] << std::endl;
        } 
        front_part = frt_pt_sm[1];
        std::cout << "front part: " << front_part << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Result as below.

```
content: AB.AC
AB.AC
AB
A
C
front part: AB
content: AB.QWE,CV
AB.QWE,CV
AB
C
V
front part: AB
content: ABC, ZXC
ABC, ZXC
ABC
X
C
front part: ABC
```

More elegant, you can use regex iterator to split string by delimiter `.` or `,` like this.

```
std::vector<std::string> contents {"AB.AC", "AB.QWE,CV", "ABC, ZXC"};

std::string front_part;
std::smatch frt_pt_sm;

std:;regex frt_pt_patt("([.,]|[^.,]+)");
for(auto content: contents) {
    std::cout << "content: " << content << std::endl;
    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit ( content.begin(), content.end(), frt_pt_patt );
    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;
    while (rit != rend) {
         std::cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
         ++rit;
    }
}
```

Result.

```
content: AB.AC
AB
.
AC
content: AB.QWE,CV
AB
.
QWE
,
CV
content: ABC, ZXC
ABC
,
 ZXC
```

Comment: Sorry,but in c++, do we need `\\w` not `\w`?

Comment: by the way, if there is some chinese character in this sentence, like "1月1日，天气晴" how to get the front part?

Comment: You can check string literals https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal